# Unit testing jersey service with tomcat and Junit

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, junit, jersey

I'm new to unit testing and I want to test some jersey services in a project.
I use Junit and tomcat.
I know there is a framework called "Jersey Test Framework", but I didn't find example of using this framework with tomcat on the Web.
Is there any way to use this framework with tomcat?
If not, please give me some example about testing a jersey service with Junit.

Comment: Documentation of the Jersey Test Framework: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test class should extend JerseyTest. In @Test annotated methods use following example:

```
PojoResource resourceNbi = resource()
                .path("/rest-patah")
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE)
                .get(resourceClass);
```

Also, override configure method. MockServer is class that have method annotated with Jersey annotations

```
@Override
protected AppDescriptor configure() {
    return new LowLevelAppDescriptor.Builder(MockServer.class)
            .clientConfig( new DefaultClientConfig())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: I get the following exception if I run that: com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.TestContainerException: The default test container factory, null, could not be instantiated